# Posting XML data to a Web Service via Console App

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, console-application

I have a web service in my QA box that accepts and process an XML string, send an email and then returns another XML string. To test it, I want to overload it by making a console app to call it by sending it an XML, making make a loop in the console app so it sends it 1,000 times in one shoot. I seen a lot of sample in the internet but I can't get them to work.

This is what I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WSStressTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            string postData = "<?xml version='1.0'?><ROOT><SOMETHING></SOMETHING></ROOT>";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://url:1111/WebService.asmx/ProcessWebService");
            request.Method = "POST";
            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);

            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
            //Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I always get an 500 error in HttpWebResponse. Now, looking at the code the only thing I can think that is missing is the name of the parameter for POST. What I mean, if I make a form

```
<form method="post" action="http://url:1111/WebService.asmx/ProcessWebService">
    <input type="text" name="sXML" /> <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

placing the xml in the input and submit will work. But I'm naming the data post to the web service **sXML**. How do I name the xml post in the console app sXML? Is that what I'm missing or is there another error in my code?

*Additional question: What would be the best way to get this to run 1,000 times. I was thinking of putting the call inside a while <1000. Is there a better way for it?*

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at tools like SoapUI? This sort of thing has already been written :)

Comment: I can't install it in the box.

Comment: How come? Can you not get it installed by the IT department, or whoever is responsible for software policy? It's crazy to write software that has already been written, with logging and stuff built-in...

Comment: I could push it and get install. But by then at least two weeks would have past, I need to test this today.

Comment: Understood - I've worked at big organizations before - never again ;-) My best suggestion is to use a web-debugging tool (Chrome, IExplore F12 Tools, Fiddler) to see what a working request looks like, then compare it to what you are sending. Not sure if that is permissible in your environment though.

Comment: Can you post some server code? The way you would handle a parameter (sXml) vs just a string would differ.

Comment: Hi Chad. A bit confused by your question, but, like I said,if I do <form method="post" action="http://url:1111/WebService.asmx/ProcessWebService">
    <input type="text" name="sXML" /> <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form> and post the xml in the textbox it works.